# ListView en Fragment no carga lista en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, listview, android-listview

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver programando en Kotlin. Estoy tratando de cargar datos en un listview que se encuentra en un fragment sin embargo cuando corro la aplicación y me dirijo al activity que contiene dicho fragment, se cierra de inmediato por problemas de NPE (NullPointerException). Sucede que cuando hago la misma lógica en java, sí corre la aplicación sin problemas. Soy nuevo en kotlin y estoy seguro que estoy omitiendo algo importante. El código en kotlin dentro del fragment es el siguiente:

```
class FavoriteFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false)

    val data = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
    data.add("Categoría 1")
    data.add("Categoría 2")
    data.add("Categoría 3")
    data.add("Categoría 4")

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context!!, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)

    val listViewSample = view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.listViewTest) as ListView

    listViewSample.adapter = adapter

    return rootView
}
```

}

El logcat es el siguiente:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: weicraft.com.servicessquad, PID: 3203
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at weicraft.com.servicessquad.fragments.FavoriteFragment.onCreateView(FavoriteFragment.kt:31)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

He probado inclusive no usar el findViewById importando directamente el elemento listView desde el layout (que Kotlin lo permite) pero tengo el mismo resultado.

No logro entender qué estoy haciendo mal y porqué en java sí me funciona a la perfección. Ya llevo tes días seguidos estancado en este punto. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar ya que tengo una app bastante avanzada en kotlin y no quisiera migrar todo a java si es que no logro entender o solucionar este problema. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que estás intentando acceder al `ListView` desde el objeto `view`

así `view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.listViewTest) as ListView` y este se encuentra nulo, ya que quien tiene la referencia a los controles de la vista es `rootView` por que se le está asignando el layout

`val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false)`

con lo que tienes que poner esto en tu código:

`val listViewSample = rootView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.listViewTest) as ListView`

Otra opción es: Utilizar **Koltlin Android Extensions** una manera para olvidarse del `findViewById` para esto tienes que integrar los siguiente plugins

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

en el archivo `build.gradle` sólo con esto puedes olvidarte de los `findViewById`

al momento de utilizarlo tienes que utilizar un `import` especial

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_favorite`

Ejemplo en tu código:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_favorite.*

class FavoriteFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val data = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
        data.add("Categoría 1")
        data.add("Categoría 2")
        data.add("Categoría 3")
        data.add("Categoría 4")

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context!!, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)

        listViewTest.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Ahora en este fragmento si quieres utilizar otro control de tu `Layout` sólo tienes utilizar el `id` del elemento.

Puedes leer este articulo [Kotlin Android Extensions: Say goodbye to findViewById](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

Comment: Gracias! No me había dado cuenta que estaba llamando desde el objeto view. Inicialmente había llamado view a la referencia de los controles de la vista pero como estuve haciendo muchas pruebas y cambios hasta antes de realizar la pregunta, en una de esas le cambié el nombre a rootview y pero no lo cambié en el código al tratar de acceder al objeto. Gracias también por el adicional  de las Extensions Functions! voy a hacerlo así para optimizar el código. Un saludo!

Comment: Excelente! puedes porfa poner la respuesta como aceptada, haz click en el check al costado de la respuesta. Por haber contribuido en la solución a tu problema.